# Cake PHP login web service load testing using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have faced problem while testing login Web service using jmeter which is build in Cake PHP, Showing message "Username and Password incorrect"

Cake Url: example

http://www.absdefered.com/testingservices/services/login/

Parameter used in HTTP Request

Method used : Post

email :${xys@gmail.com}

password :${password}

device_id :624d90909090090900009171355ce92deb486f014e251380b18

I have changed web service url to fix this issue.

http://www.absdefered.com/testingservices/services/login.php?login

[image]

Now i am not getting message in listener (View Result tree)Result data "Login Successfully"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you need to construct your request a little bit differently.

- For [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)-based web services you need to send [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)
- For [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web services you need to send [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Appropriate `Content-Type` header needs to be provided via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
 - `application/soap+xml` - for SOAP
 - `application/json` - for REST

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for more details.